# MySQL query performance degrades on same server in different directory

Tags: mysql, apache, ubuntu-18.04, php-7.2

I have a very strange issue.
I have a MySQL query very optimized which return information within milli seconds. My application is deployed on [apache2] `/var/www/html` working good.
same application with a little thematic change deployed to `/var/www/beta` taking almost 56+ seconds to load.
Both applications configured with same user/password of MySQL.

`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.30, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

`PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.6`

`Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)`

`DB Size: 16gb`

`App: Codeigniter 3`

--

Please ask me questions to further clarify the issue instead of reporting or making not an issue etc.

Thanks

Comment: Enable the MySQL slow query log and se if its showing up as a query. Try to minimize your beta test case down to something repdoucable. Are they connecting to the same database server? Are they using the same MySQL data? If different are the database structure or configuration different?

Comment: both are connecting to same instance of database and table. Also both apps are on same server just in different directory.